# QGIS: Point object is not displayed, then layerstyle disapperas as well

Tags: point, style, feature-layer, visibility

I have a windturbine displayed as a point layer with a style for visibility.
If the window doesn't show the point feature, then the style disappears as well. It would be better, if the style stays, even if the point feature is not anymore in the displayed window.
I searched already all the style options, but couldn't fix the problem.
Trying to make it clear:
Grey area(point feature) visible, then yellow area visible as well.
Grey area NOT visible, yellow area not visible, even if it should be there.

Here two screenshots:
[image: point feature visibel(grey)]

[image: point feature gone, but yellow area should be visible]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to display the symbology if the actual geometry is not in focus. If nobody came with an answer that prove me wrong your solution would be to create a buffer around your point (you will need an actual layer, geometry generator will behave the same as what you already experience)

Comment: Interestingly, a virtual layer creating such buffer do work (`select st_buffer(geometry,1000) from pt`), though I have had inconsistent results in the past

Comment: Geometry generated symbols are only visible as long as the original geometry is within the map canvas. Bonus hint: The competition might be on GIS.SE, so you might want to remove relevant project info.

Comment: thanks for answering...looks like it stays like it is.